# The R-function history() doesn't accept my pattern regexp

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I experimented with a pattern to reject any line beginning with 0 to N spaces followed by a "#" .  At [this test webpage](https://www.regextester.com/15), the following pattern works fine:

```
^(?!(\s*[#])).*
```

I used as test lines of text the following:

```
 #tbadword
    #test
one two
  abadwo#rds
#three
```

And only the "non-comment" lines are selected.
But in `R`, using the Windows `Rgui` , if I try

```
> history(Inf, pattern = '^(?!(\\s*[#])).*' )
```

I get the error message "Invalid regexp"  .

Can someone point out what `R` is unhappy with here? Do I need to set a global "perl=TRUE" or some such thing?   Or is there a  simpler way to do this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how can `str_extract` be used to obtain history? I thought `str_extract` is used to extract text from a given string. How is it useful here?

Comment: I thought OP had a string. Never mind. `history(Inf, pattern="^(?!\\s*#)", perl=TRUE)` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have R [`history`](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/utils/html/savehistory.html) parse your regex with a PCRE regex engine:

```
history(Inf, pattern="^(?!\\s*#)", perl=TRUE)
```

Now, `^(?!\s*#)` will be parsed correctly as

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s*#)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location (i.e. at the start of the string) there are 0+ whitespaces and then `#`.

Although the [solution with `invert=TRUE` and an opposite regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51216872/3832970) is more natural for the current scenario, you may need the more advanced regex functionality for other cases, and `perl=TRUE` will help cover them.

Answer (score 2):

The `history()` command has a `...` for values that will be passed to `grep()`, so you can use the `invert=` flag rather than a look-ahead to find what you need. How about

```
history(Inf, pattern="^\\s*#", invert=TRUE)
```

Comment: ahhh... silly me for not having read `?history` in enough detail (and `?grep`)